# Not able to pass collections classes as a parameter in a method with generic

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

The motive of my program is used to add random string into collection classes like ArrayList,LinkedList and HashSet. I have created a class with generic parameters and want to pass those class reference into one method which accept a parameter of type collection.

When I create a object of type ArrayList and HashSet there is no compilation error. But when I create with LnkedList I am getting compilation error.

```
public class CollectionPerformace<T extends Collection<String>> {

public void calculatePerformance(T elements) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        elements.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    CollectionPerformace<ArrayList<String>> arrayListPerformance = new 
     CollectionPerformace<>();
    arrayListPerformance.calculatePerformance(arrayList);
    **CollectionPerformace<LinkedList<String>> linkedListPerformance = new 
    CollectionPerformace<>();**
    linkedListPerformance.calculatePerformance(linkedList);
    CollectionPerformace<HashSet<String>> hashSetPerformance = new 
     CollectionPerformace<>();
    hashSetPerformance.calculatePerformance(hashSet);
    CollectionPerformace<TreeSet<String>> treeSetPerformance = new 
    CollectionPerformace<>();
    treeSetPerformance.calculatePerformance(treeSet);
  }
}
```

**ERROR:**
Getting error in the line marked with bold.
Multiple markers at this line
    - Bound mismatch: The type LinkedList is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter > of the type CollectionPerformace
    - Cannot infer type arguments for CollectionPerformace<>

I need help from any one.

Comment: I'm not getting any error with this code. I'm using JDK 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM used?
For Java 8 this is a valid code and it works fine.

HTH,
Gal